# What can be the probable escape speed from the event horizon of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes

Is there any approximate escape speed value from the event horizon of a black hole or is it infinite ?

Comment: I assume you mean "event horizon" rather than "surface"?

Comment: Yes yes ri8 my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the black hole event horizon then the escape speed is $c$, the speed of light.  This is in fact the definition of the event horizon radius, known as the Schwarzschild Radius and given by the following formula:
$$
R = \frac{2 G M}{c^2}
$$
You can use this formula for computing escape velocities for larger radius values.  Instead of the letter $c$ used to represent the speed of light, just use $v$ and resolve for $v$ as:
$$
v = \sqrt{\frac{2 G M}{r}}
$$
Where $r$ is the radius of choice and $M$ is mass of black hole and $G$ is Newton's Gravitational Constant.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the horizon corresponds to the locations where the escape speed would be $c$, the speed of light, and maximum speed of causality.